# GetColumn DataTable in for

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a `DataTable`

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable ();
dt.Load (..etc..
```

with the following data (example):

```
str_foto   int_ID   strRef
--------------------------
1.jpg        1      tesxt01
2.jpg        2      Teszt02
```

etc.

I have a `DropDownList`

```
DDL_Imagens.DataSource = dt;
DDL_Imagens.DataTextField = "strRef";
DDL_Imagens.DataValueField = "int_ID";
DDL_Imagens.DataBind ();
```

I want to add an attribute to each item.

```
for (int i = 0; i <DDL_Imagens.Items.Count; i + +)
{
       ListItem item = DDL_Imagens.Items[i];
       item.Attributes ["data-img-src"] = dt.Rows[0].DataBoundItem;//???
}
```

How do I add a column `str_foto` from the `DataTable` to the `DropDownList`?

I tried:

```
dt.Rows.Rows[0].DataBoundItem;
dt.Rows.Rows[0].ToString();
```

The end result should be:

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$DDL_Imagens" id="ctl00_MainContent_DDL_Imagens">
    <option value="11713536" data-img-src="1.jpg">100</option>
    <option value="11753979" data-img-src="2.jpg">434</option>
    <option value="11754913" data-img-src="3.jpg">rtr4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i <DDL_Imagens.Items.Count; i + +)
   {
       ListItem item = DDL_Imagens.Items[i];
       item.Attributes.Add("data-img-src", Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][0]))
   }
```

Or

```
for (int i = 0; i <DDL_Imagens.Items.Count; i + +)
       {
           ListItem item = DDL_Imagens.Items[i];
           item.Attributes.Add("data-img-src", Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["str_foto"]))
       }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper syntax is:

```
item.Attributes.Add("data-img-src", dt.Rows.Rows[0].DataBoundItem);
```

instead of:

```
item.Attributes ["data-img-src"] = dt.Rows.Rows[0].DataBoundItem;//???
```

Comment: no. System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'DataBoundItem' and no extension method 'DataBoundItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)